# my tensorflow image classification model predictions are always 0% even though on the training and validation it made it to 90% accuracy and low loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision

I will try to explain my question the best I can:
I am trying to make a model that will classify if an image has a crosswalk in it or not, my code is this:

```
import os, warnings
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
pretrained_base  = VGG16(weights='imagenet')

def set_seed(seed=31415):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    tf.random.set_seed(seed)
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
    #os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'
set_seed()

plt.rc('figure', autolayout=True)
plt.rc('axes', labelweight='bold', labelsize='large',
       titleweight='bold', titlesize=18, titlepad=10)
plt.rc('image', cmap='magma')
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

ds_train_ = image_dataset_from_directory(
    f'E:/privatelessons/crosswalkornot',
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='binary',
    image_size=[128, 128],
    interpolation='nearest',
    batch_size=64,
    shuffle=True,
)
ds_valid_ = image_dataset_from_directory(
    f'E:/privatelessons/crosswalkornotvalid',
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='binary',
    image_size=[128, 128],
    interpolation='nearest',
    batch_size=64,
    shuffle=False,
)
def convert_to_float(image, label):
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)
    return image, label

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
ds_train = (
    ds_train_
    .map(convert_to_float)
    .cache()
    .prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
)
ds_valid = (
    ds_valid_
    .map(convert_to_float)
    .cache()
    .prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
)

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
# these are a new feature in TF 2.2
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing


# pretrained_base = tf.keras.models.load_model(
#     f'D:/vgg16',
# )

pretrained_base.trainable = False
print("I got here")
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.InputLayer(input_shape=[128, 128, 3]),
    #
    # # Data Augmentation
    preprocessing.RandomFlip(mode='horizontal'),
    preprocessing.RandomFlip(mode='vertical'),
    preprocessing.RandomRotation(factor=0.10),
    preprocessing.RandomTranslation(height_factor=0.1, width_factor=0.1),
    # # Block One
    layers.BatchNormalization(renorm=True),
    layers.Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'),
    layers.MaxPool2D(),

    # Block Two
    layers.BatchNormalization(renorm=True),
    layers.Conv2D(filters=6, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'),
    layers.MaxPool2D(),

    # Block Three
    layers.BatchNormalization(renorm=True),
    layers.Conv2D(filters=12, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'),
    layers.Conv2D(filters=12, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'),
    layers.MaxPool2D(),
    # pretrained_base,
    # Head
    layers.BatchNormalization(renorm=True),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
])

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=['binary_accuracy'],
)
history = model.fit(
    ds_train,
    validation_data=ds_valid,
    epochs=30,
    verbose=1,
)

model.save("personalmodel")
print("I got here 4")
import pandas as pd

history_frame = pd.DataFrame(history.history)

history_frame.loc[:, ['loss', 'val_loss']].plot()
plt.show()
history_frame.loc[:, ['binary_accuracy', 'val_binary_accuracy']].plot();
plt.show()
```

I trained it on a dataset I found on kaggle of crosswalks its not big so I think that is the problem, the graphs that it produced are those:
[validation and training loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNcu4.png)
[accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3lsd.png)
now when I try to test it on some random crosswalk image I found like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('personalmodel')
# print(model.evaluate(ds_test,return_dict=True))
img_path = f"imagepath"
img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
    img_path,
    target_size=(128, 128),
    interpolation='nearest'
)
img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)  # Create batch axis
img_array = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img_array, dtype=tf.float32)

# Make predictions on the image
prediction = model.predict(img_array)
print(prediction)
if prediction > 0.5:
    print('There is a crosswalk in the image.')
else:
    print('There is no crosswalk in the image.')
```

it prints out 0% no matter the image, is it because my dataset is small
500 train 100 validation, or a problem in my model sequential? I didn't want to use a pretrained base.
any suggestions?

Comment: I would guess you forgot to apply the same preprocessing when predicting. Try normalizing your inputs between 0 and 1 (by diving by 255.)

Comment: I changed the preproccesing when predicting to fit exactly it still gave 0 but when I changed my base to a pretrained base it gave better results, so my guess is my base is not good, I will try what you said normalizing my inputs

Comment: check out the edit I did, it still give 0 percent on any image

Comment: `convert_image_dtype` doesn't normalize the image because `img_to_array` already performs the conversion to float without normalizing. Try to use `img_to_array(img, dtype="uint8")` instead.

Comment: it did produce a result different than 0 so I think we fixed that problem but I guess my model is bad because the result was 0.00467633

Comment: I think I'll just use a pretrained base, do you have any recommendation on one?

Comment: You are using very less neuron units in Convolutional layers of the model. So this could be the reason of model is not performing well. Please share the dataset link to reproduce the issue if the issue still persists.